# How to get data from passportjs validator in node js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-jwt

I'm using passport js for validate users. Here is my strategy.

```
    passport.use(
  new Strategy(opts, async ( payload , done) => {
    try {
      let user = await User.findById(payload.id);
      if (!user) throw new Error("User not found");
      if(user.role !== payload.role) throw new Error("Hacker");
      return done(null, user.getUserInfo());
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      done(null, false);
    }
  })
);
```

And if all OK, I'm returning a user.getUserInfo(). Now, here is my route:

```
    router.get("url", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

And now, when user pass the validator, how can I get this data from return done() statement, or it is unrealistic to take data from there. I'm a new in node js, so I don't know how to do that, or Is real to take data from passport.authenticate()?

Answer (score 0):

In routes, Do:

> {session: true}

and inside *req.user*, you will get the user data.

Otherwise, a work around can be to set user data in request just before *done* callback function.

```
req.userData = user.getUserInfo();
```